# Foundation reveal modal stop executing javascript like alert();

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I am writing a program with foundation reveal modal. When a modal is opened, the javascript need to stop executing until user has press the button in the modal, then only the javascript continue execute. This is more similar like Alert() function in javascript. Is it possible?

I need some guidelines, thanks!

Comment: I guess you mean something like promises / async/await.

Comment: Where is your code? Please see "How to ask a good question" - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

HTML:

```
 <div id="modal_div" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="okbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ok</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end html-->
```

Javascript:

```
function hide_modal_on_click(top_level_modal_div, button) {

    var top_level_modal_div = $("#modal_div").show();

    var button = $("#okbtn").on('click', function() {
      top_level_modal_div.hide();
    })
  }

  hide_modal_on_click();
```